# Attaching Apache HTTP Client to RESTlet client

Tags: rest, restlet, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm using RESTlet as Server and Client. Server is running over Tomcat and I can access it from browser.

For Client, I'm using org.restlet.resource.ClientResource. It works fine if I send a few requests to that server, but if I send a few hundred calls it breaks:

```
Fev 20, 2013 12:59:43 PM org.restlet.engine.connector.ClientConnectionHelper start
INFO: Starting the internal [HTTP/1.1] client
(some calls work)
Fev 20, 2013 1:00:49 PM org.restlet.util.SelectionRegistration block
WARNING: The thread blocked at the cyclic barrier has timed out
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier.dowait(CyclicBarrier.java:250)
    at java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier.await(CyclicBarrier.java:427)
    at org.restlet.util.SelectionRegistration.block(SelectionRegistration.java:191)
    at org.restlet.engine.io.NbChannelInputStream.onFill(NbChannelInputStream.java:230)
    at org.restlet.engine.io.Buffer.process(Buffer.java:601)
    at org.restlet.engine.io.NbChannelInputStream.read(NbChannelInputStream.java:307)
    at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
    at org.restlet.engine.io.BioUtils.copy(BioUtils.java:80)
    at org.restlet.engine.io.NioUtils.copy(NioUtils.java:147)
    at org.restlet.representation.ReadableRepresentation.write(ReadableRepresentation.java:104)
    at org.restlet.representation.ChannelRepresentation.write(ChannelRepresentation.java:76)
    at org.restlet.representation.ChannelRepresentation.write(ChannelRepresentation.java:82)

Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: The thread blocked at the cyclic barrier has timed out.
    at org.restlet.util.SelectionRegistration.block(SelectionRegistration.java:197)
    at org.restlet.engine.io.NbChannelInputStream.onFill(NbChannelInputStream.java:230)
    at org.restlet.engine.io.Buffer.process(Buffer.java:601)
    at org.restlet.engine.io.NbChannelInputStream.read(NbChannelInputStream.java:307)
    at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
    at org.restlet.engine.io.BioUtils.copy(BioUtils.java:80)
    at org.restlet.engine.io.NioUtils.copy(NioUtils.java:147)
    at org.restlet.representation.ReadableRepresentation.write(ReadableRepresentation.java:104)
    at org.restlet.representation.ChannelRepresentation.write(ChannelRepresentation.java:76)
    at org.restlet.representation.ChannelRepresentation.write(ChannelRepresentation.java:82)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier.dowait(CyclicBarrier.java:250)
    at java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier.await(CyclicBarrier.java:427)
    at org.restlet.util.SelectionRegistration.block(SelectionRegistration.java:191)
    ... 11 more
```

I wanna use Apache HTTP Client to be able to do more calls, but I can't find documentation on how to attach it.

Comment: I confirm this is a bug due to the NioUtils.copy() new implementation. See this GitHub issue for details: https://github.com/restlet/restlet-framework-java/issues/805#issuecomment-34860997

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every evidence points this error to be internal in RESTlet client. Instead of using it, I used `URL.getInputStream()`, and with that I was able to easily do 10K sequential calls to my RESTlet server. Of course URL is way simple, it's unable to handle errors and shouldn't be used in production, but it proved RESTlet isn't worth it.

I also managed to make Benchmark comparing Axis2 and RESTlet as server, and they had same performance taking 3-5 milisecs to answer a request, I expected REST to be faster... I implemented REST server directly from Servlet and it too 0-1 milisecs to respond. Because of that I decided to drop REST and stick with SOAP Axis2, it's not slower than RESTlet and just a few milisecs slower than Servlet, but it way more flexible and powerful.

Comment: The Restlet API has an integration with HttpURLConnection (now the default HTTP client since version 2.2 RC1), so no reason why Restlet would had any significant hit. We do have a bug to fix as reported here but using Restlet API high-level features isn't orthogonal to having good performance.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but on a live production machine which caused my server to eat up 100% of CPU. I was able to solve it by going back to using `restlet 2.1.0` instead of `2.1.2`. Not really an answer to the underlying problem, but definitely a solution.